# Copying cells and multiply them, then paste each cell beneath each other

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy 90 cells, and each cell has to be copied into another column. Every copied cell have to become 52 identical cells beneath each other and all the cells should be created without any blanks. Therefore, I should end up with 4680 cells, but the code doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

```
Sub Copy_bud()
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim i, j As Long
Dim kopi As Boolean

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Ark1")

n = WS.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
j = 1

For i = 1 To n
    While kopi = True
        WS.Cells(i, 1).Select
        Selection.copy
        WS.Cells(j, 5).Paste
        j = j + 51
    Wend 
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: not sure, but try ws.range(cells(j,5),cells(j+51,5)).select    ws.paste  What do you mean by multiply them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly as it wasn't obvious to me by looking at your code. But maybe you've been looking for something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_bud()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet

Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Ark1")

lngLastRow = WS.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For lngRow = 1 To lngLastRow
    WS.Range(WS.Cells(1, 4 + lngRow), WS.Cells(lngLastRow, 4 + lngRow)).Value2 = WS.Cells(lngRow, 1).Value2
Next lngRow

End Sub
```